# Displaying current path in the window title with byobu on centos

Tags: centos, tmux, byobu

I am used to displaying my current path in the linux terminal window title when using rxvt with something like:

```
PS1="\[\033]0;\u@\h: \w\007\][${LOGNAME}@${HOSTNAME}] > "
```

from my .bashrc

I can't find a way to do that in byobu (with tmux) on centos. Does anyone have a clue on how to do that, or in the byobu status line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out the way to do that in the byobu status bar.

The problem with CentOS 6, is that the tmux version that comes from the standard repo. is v1.6, and we need at least 1.8 to achieve the result.

So install tmux from the latest sources like explained here: https://gist.github.com/sturadnidge/4185338

NB: Kill old tmux sessions before running byobu again.

And then use the following setting in your $HOME/.byobu/.tmux.conf

```
set -g status-left '#{pane_current_path} '
```